# Why don't use repository in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, repository

I have a partial view that loops through its Model (a list of things) to show the thing.Name and three integer values that are counts of related entities.

First of all, I tried putting: (pseudo-razor)

```
foreach(thing in Model){
    @thing.Name : 
        @thing.related.entities.where(condition1).Count()
        @thing.related.entities.where(condition2).Count()
        @thing.related.entities.where(condition3).Count()
}
```

But its really slow... so I created a function in the ThingRepository that does same queries faster, something like this  (pseudo-code)

```
function GetCountofRelatedEntities(relatedID,condition){
    return db.entities.where(relatedID==relatedID && condition).count()
}
```

and its much faster, so I want to call it. I think I should call it from the controller, but then I need a ViewModel to keep a (thing, int, int, int) collection as the model, or I can use the ViewBag extremely to pass the results to the view, but, and here is the question:
Why not simply use the repository from the view? whats wrong with this code in the view?  (pseudo-razor)

```
@repo=new ThingRepository()
foreach(thing in Model){
    @thing.Name : 
        @repo.GetCountofRelatedEntities(thing.relatedID,condition1)
        @repo.GetCountofRelatedEntities(thing.relatedID,condition1)
        @repo.GetCountofRelatedEntities(thing.relatedID,condition1)
}
```

Could you tell me why I shouldn't instantiate the repository inside a View? Or I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One purpose of the MVC pattern is to provide a structure that fits a wide range of common programming situations. To simplify:

- Model: Describes the shape of your application, i.e. the parts of your software specific to your business.
- View: Display the data to the user and transmit user events to the server.
- Controller: Acts as a middleman between the view and the model.

What you're proposing "works," in the sense that it gets the data on the page where you want it. In the short term, it appears to be saving you time and effort, as you don't have to bother with controllers, viewbags, etc.

However, you are breaking the MVC structure in a way that you will probably regret later on. For example, say in a few weeks your boss comes to you and says, "Hey, you know that page you added to display that list of entities? We need to do some filtering and sorting on it. And I need it yesterday."

Now you're faced with a choice: Do I add this filtering logic to my view page and meet the deadline, or do I take the time to move the data access code to a controller and rework my view, at the risk of missing the deadline and breaking what's already working?

You'll probably take the easy way out and add the logic to the view, and now you've got a growing mess on your hands. We've been down this road with VB6 and Webforms apps with 6,000-line codebehind files. Trust me--you don't want to go there.

Another problem is that the MVC structure is well understood by the programming community. If someone else comes along and tries to work on your code, you're making it harder for them by deviating from the conventional approach.

The MVC structure is time tested and sound. Until you fully understand its purpose and the benefits it provides, try to follow it closely. It's not a good idea to break the rules until you have a firm grasp on them.

Answer (score 6):

> Why not simply use the repository from the view?

Because you are violating the MVC design pattern. A view's responsibility is not to fetch data. It is to display data that it is being passed to it from the controller under the form a view model. And it's as simple as that.

You could call repositories or whatever you like in your views but just don't tag your questions with asp.net-mvc anymore because you are no longer doing any MVC. I mean you could do whatever you like - you could even write SQL queries in your view if you want.

But the whole point of the MVC design pattern is to separate the data retrieval logic from the presentation logic.

Comment: But I'm using MVC! (I have models, views and controllers.. and the dll ;-)) and it saves time to me every day at work, then if doing this I save more time, even if violating patterns, and it has not security implications or any other problems that I can't see.. why not? only the pattern?

Comment: @Peto, oh no, if you start calling repositories in your views you are missing the whole point of MVC. I mean I won't convince you: as I said in my answer you could even write SQL queries in a view in something that you call ASP.NET MVC application. If you think that this is better and you feel more productive then good for you, feel free to go ahead and implement it in your project. I just wanted to point out what the correct way is so that other people that might have the same question in the future and stumble upon this question don't make the same mistake as you.

Answer (score 2):

My main objection would be the separation of concerns.  Once you start hitting your DB from your view, your "view" really isn't just a view anymore.  It's really handy to have a clean separation between your data access and your view.

Why is this separation of concerns important?  It makes it easier to work with systems that are composed with these clean separations.  When you need to adjust what data is retrieved, you'll never need to fuss with the view. So long as the view gets the right value, it will display it correctly.  Likewise, if you want to change how values are displayed, you can modify the view without any chance of borking the data.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you should not have any logic in your `View` because this is not the `MVC` approach.

MVC is `Seperation of concern`.

So you should create your ViewModel wich contains **ALL** the data your View needs.